# Is it possible to submit cookies in an Android DownloadManager

Tags: android, cookies, download

I'm using the android `DownloadManager` API to download files from my school's server. I have permission to access these files with a login, but what I haven't been able to figure out is how to submit cookies with my `DownloadManager.Request` The download code is below. `dm` is a global `DownloadManager`, and `url` is a php download script which redirects to a file, usually pdf/doc/etc.

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
dm.enqueue(request);

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
startActivity(i);
```

This works fine, but I get an html file downloaded, which is the login page of my school's website. Obviously I need to submit the user's session cookies somehow, but I can't see any way of doing this in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Cookies are sent via an HTTP header (named, appropriately enough, "Cookie"), and fortunately, DownloadManager.Request [has a method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#addRequestHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to add your own headers.

So what you'd want to do is something like this:

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url)); 
request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", "contents");
dm.enqueue(request);
```

You'll have to replace "contents" with the actual cookie contents, of course. The [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) class should be useful to get the current cookie for the site, but if that fails, another option would be to have your application make a login request and grab the returned cookie.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was already managing cookies manually in a `Map<String, String>` so it was as simple as formatting that as `KEY1=VALUE1;KEY2=VALUE2;` and passing it to the function you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: This is just perfect - been down a few other roads but this nailed it! I get my cookies from onPageFinished by calling "CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);" and I can then use the result directly as Cookie values!

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve cookies with CookieManager like below (where I used webview):

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            String cookieString = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

        }
    });

    //Enable Javascript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Clear All and load url
    webView.loadUrl(URL_TO_SERVE);
```

And then pass it to DownloadManager:

```
  //Create a DownloadManager.Request with all the information necessary to start the download
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            .setTitle("File")// Title of the Download Notification
            .setDescription("Downloading")// Description of the Download Notification
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)// Visibility of the download Notification
            .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))// Uri of the destination file
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)// Set if download is allowed on Mobile network
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookieString);
    /*request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", cookieString);*/
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);// enqueue puts the download request in the queue.
```